# Синхронный RxJava запрос

Tags: android, kotlin, rxjava, okhttp

У меня есть OkHttp Interceptor, который добавляет headers к запросам.
Проблема в том, что он делает это асинхронно(использую RxJava2) и запрос уходить до модификации Interceptor.
Код Interceptor:

```
class AddCookiesInterceptor: Interceptor {

    @Inject
    lateinit var cookiesDao: CookiesDao

    init {
        App.getAppComponent().inject(this)
    }

    @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val builder = chain.request().newBuilder()
        cookiesDao.getAll()
            .subscribe { cookies ->
            builder.addHeader("Cookie", "JWT=" + cookies.jwt)
        }
        return chain.proceed(builder.build())
    }
}
```

Пробовал делать `cookiesDao.getAll().blockingFirst()`, но это не помогает.
Метод Dao возвращает `Observable<Cookie>`, где Cookie - data class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CookiesDao, наверное, из библиотеки Room? Коли так, то просто сделайте в Dao классе метод getAll который не Observable возвращает, а просто Cookie - так вам не нужен будет Rx и не надо будет выяснять почему blockingFirst не работает, хотя и должен, по идее

Comment: В таком случае работает, благодарю.
Запрос куки из бд конечно занимает секунду, но все же, насколько правильно выполнять это в main thread?

Comment: По идее оно должно не на главном потоке исполняться. Если у вас для Room явно не прописано разрешение на запросы в главном потоке и приложение не падает с соответствующей ошибкой - значит запрос в интерсепторе, как и положено, не на главном потоке выполняется. Вы можете это проверить, выведя из intercept метода имя потока примерно так: `println(Thread.currentThread())`

Comment: Нет, пришлось явно указать ```allowMainThreadQueries()``` , иначе ругается на запросы в main thread

Comment: @dbuzin, крайне странно. У меня не в главном потоке выполняется, только что проверил.

Comment: если закомментить ```allowMainThreadQueries()```, то вылетает исключение, но ```Thread.currentThread().name``` говорит RxCachedThreadScheduler-1

Comment: У меня тот же поток и allowMainThreadQueries() нет. Предполагаю, что оно у вас не в этом месте падает. Что в логах? МОжет вам отдельный вопрос про это создать?